Using MPI reduce (lowercase) for dynamic process management
I'm wondering whether it is possible in Python to use MPI's reduce function (lowercase) when doing DPM.
Currently I have a working code that explicitly uses memory buffers with Reduce (uppercase). Is there a way to not explicitly define buffers and use lower case functions instead?
The client/parent code:
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy
import sys

comm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn(sys.executable,
                           args=['server.py'],
                           maxprocs=5)

N = numpy.array(100, 'i')
comm.Bcast([N, MPI.INT], root=MPI.ROOT)
R = numpy.array(0.0, 'd')
comm.Reduce(None, [R, MPI.DOUBLE],
            op=MPI.SUM, root=MPI.ROOT)
print(R)

comm.Disconnect()

The server/child code:
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy

comm = MPI.Comm.Get_parent()
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

N = numpy.array(0, dtype='i')
comm.Bcast([N, MPI.INT], root=0)

R = numpy.array(N * rank, dtype='d')
comm.Reduce([R, MPI.DOUBLE], None,
            op=MPI.SUM, root=0)

comm.Disconnect()


I don't see a problem in doing what you are asking for. client2.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python

from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy
import sys

comm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn(sys.executable,
                           args=['server2.py'],
                           maxprocs=5)

#N = [100,]
N = 100
N=comm.bcast(N, root=MPI.ROOT)
#R = [.0,]
R = .0
R = comm.reduce(R, op=MPI.SUM, root=MPI.ROOT)
print(R)

comm.Disconnect()

server2.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy

comm = MPI.Comm.Get_parent()
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

N = rank*23
#N = [rank*23,]
N = comm.bcast(N, root=0)
#R = list([1.*rank*i for i in N])
R = 1.*rank*N
R = comm.reduce(R, op=MPI.SUM, root=0)

comm.Disconnect()

Executing this, prints 1000.0 as expected and is the same what your code prints. Using the commented lines with the lists instead prints [0.0, 100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 400.0], which might be surprising, but actually makes perfect sense. It is the result of summing up lists, i.e. applying the + operator to the 5 lists. This result is not specific to DPM, but would be the same with normal MPI-parallel execution.
